# Unable to add all values to a map

Tags: java

In the below for loops :

```
for(int i = 0; i < initialSplit.length; i++){ //initialSplit - contains one DB record (row)
    String [] cellVal = (initialSplit[i]).split("~");
    System.out.println(cellVal[0]);
    for(int j = 0; j < cellVal.length; j++){ //cellVal - contains value of each cell in a record
        map.put(dataIndexString[j], cellVal[j]);
        System.out.println(j+"--"+dataIndexString[j] + " -- key : value -- "+cellVal[j]);
    }
    items.add(map);//The last record alone adds into the ArrayList 'items'
}
```

The length of the `initialSplit` is 10 (10 records) and the `cellVal.length` is 21.

On adding the `HashMap`s to the `ArrayList`, the last map is added 10 times, instead of the 10 maps, each added once. I also tried to `map.clear()`, but maybe in the wrong place.
I am unable to spot the mistake. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Why do you think 10 **different** maps would be added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The is only one map instance which you add multiple times to the list.

In order to have difference maps added to the list, you have to created multiple instances :

```
    map = new HashMap<...>();
    for(int j = 0; j < cellVal.length; j++){ //cellVal - contains value of each cell in a record
        map.put(dataIndexString[j], cellVal[j]);
        System.out.println(j+"--"+dataIndexString[j] + " -- key : value -- "+cellVal[j]);
    }
    items.add(map);
```